# Mocha before executes after It block

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to do unit test case for node.js using mocha and chai.

**index.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    setA: function () {
        return new Promise(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("aaaa");
                a = 1;
            }, 2000)

        })
    }
}
```

**index.spec.js**

```js
var assert = require("assert");
var SetA = require("./index")
a = 0;
before(function() {
  SetA.setA();

});
it('a should be set to 1', function() {
  assert(a === 1);
});
```

A promise is returned from the SetA method in index.js file. before block is not waiting to be completed. After 2000 milliseconds only the before block is completed.so my test cases are failing. Mocha version is **5.2.0**

**Test cases**

[image]

How can I make the before block synchronous so that it will move to It block only after it completed the execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocha understands promises, so you should be able to just return the promise generated by `SetA`:

```
before(function() {
  return SetA.setA(); 
});
```

Also looking at your function `SetA` -- you are never resolving that promise. You'll need something like:

```
module.exports = {
    setA: function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) { //<< resolve
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("aaaa");
                a = 1;
                resolve() //<< call resolve when you're done
            }, 2000)

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried that .but it throws an error like timeout of 2000ms exceeded,For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.I changed the timeout to 1500ms still i am getting this error

Comment: @Gopesh see edit, your setA function never resolves the promise. Also mocha has a default limit of 2000ms, so you should set your timeout to something less than that or change the default time in mocha. You can do by passing a flag to mocha: `mocha test.js --timeout 5000`